# How to pass a table-valued parameter from C# to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, parameter-passing, odp.net

I have an Oracle stored procedure named `CREATE_CASE_EXL`:

```
PROCEDURE  CREATE_CASE_EXL(P_RICdata RICTab,
                       P_sACTION_TYPE IN VARCHAR2);
```

where `RICTab` is a custom type:

```
TYPE RICTab IS TABLE OF MMSRRicRec  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE MMSRRicRec IS RECORD
 ( RIC        VARCHAR2(32),
   FID_NO     NUMBER(8),
   REC_ID     NUMBER(8),
   MMS_ACTION VARCHAR2(1)
 );
```

I run this code in PL/SQL to execute `CREATE_CASE_EXL`:

```
DECLARE
pTE_RICS     RICTab 

BEGIN
    pTE_RICS(1).RIC  := 'RIC1';
    pTE_RICS(1).FID_NO := NULL;
    pTE_RICS(1).REC_ID := 3;
    pTE_RICS(1).MMS_ACTION := 'A';

    pTE_RICS(1).RIC  := 'RIC2';
    pTE_RICS(1).FID_NO := NULL;
    pTE_RICS(1).REC_ID := 4;
    pTE_RICS(1).MMS_ACTION := 'A';

    CREATE_CASE_EXL( pTE_RICS , 'A');

END;
```

I need to execute something similar in .NET.  Can you please advise how could I pass a parameter as a table of data to an Oracle stored procedure? Should I use a UDT for this task?

Comment: Have a look here. http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-pass-arrays-from-net-c-to-oracle.html

Comment: tranceporter, thank you for the link, but in the example they use single dimension array and in my case I need 2 dimension array which has 2 columns - RIC, FID_NO, REC_ID, MMS_ACTION. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually I found that it's supported, but you have to use Oracle UDT for that purpose.

Here's link to the resources which I used to solve the issue:
http://appsjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html

Big thanks to everybody for the advices!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently supported. I think you will have to use some workaround.

1) XML

2) smart associative array

```
pTE_RICS(1).RIC  := 'RIC1'; -> pTE_RICS("item[0].RIC")  := 'RIC1';
```

We were choosing between them a year ago and we chose XML. (and also trying to get your case working but without success)

Comment: Hi, actually I found that it's supported, but you have to use Oracle UDT for that reason. Here's couple of links describing how to do this: