# Oracle Stored Procedure with variable number of IN parameters of the same type

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which looks like the following:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE QueryMultipleValues
(
  VALUE_X1 IN VARCHAR2  
, VALUE_X2 IN VARCHAR2  
) AS
Cursor cur1 is
Select Table1.Value, Table2.OtherValue
From Table1
Join Table2 on Table1.OtherValue = Table2.OtherValue
Where Table2.OtherValue = VALUE_X1 or Table2.OtherValue = VALUE_X2
BEGIN
--display the results
END QueryMultipleValues;
```

I know the names in that code are vague, so if it helps, let's say I'm trying to get a list of names based on an ID number being used as the parameter.  Right now the stored procedure requires two, and exactly two input parameters.  Is it possible to adjust this code so that it will take a variable number of input parameters?  For example, 'Execute QueryMultipleValues(123, 456, 789, 999)' or 'Execute QueryMultipleValues(123)'?  I think I can change the WHERE clause to use IN instead of = , but I can't figure out how to get the procedure to accept a variable number of IN parameters.  I'd really appreciate some help.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't accept multiple parameters, but you can accept a table valued parameter which has many rows. Check out this answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712355/how-to-pass-a-table-valued-parameter-from-c-sharp-to-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass in a list of parameters, you should really use a collection rather than passing in multiple parameters.

```
CREATE TYPE id_arr 
    AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

create or replace PROCEDURE QueryMultipleValues (
  p_ids IN id_arr
)
```

If you want your procedure to accept a variable number of parameters, assuming that you can determine the maximum number of parameters you want to accept in advance, you can define a procedure with optional parameters

```
create or replace PROCEDURE QueryMultipleValues (
  p_id1 IN VARCHAR2,
  p_id2 IN VARCHAR2 = null,
  p_id3 IN VARCHAR2 = null,
  ..
  p_idN IN VARCHAR2 = null,
)
```

can be called with between 1 and N parameters.

Comment: Thanks!  The optional parameters solution will do the trick, that's exactly what I was looking for.