# How to pass c# object to Oracle?

Tags: c#

I have my c# object

```
public class Person
{
    
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Surname{ get;set; }
    public string Phone { get;set; }
    public string Address { get;set; }
    // More properties here
}
```

So, i am passing it to oracle stored procedure this way

```
var con = new OracleConnection("connection string");
var com = con.CreateCommand("create_user");
com.Parameters.Add("name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Name , ParameterDirection.Input);
com.Parameters.Add("surname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Surname, ParameterDirection.Input);
com.Parameters.Add("phone", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Phone , ParameterDirection.Input);
// More adds here
```

my oracle procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Person(
       name IN Person.name%TYPE,
       surname IN Person.surname%TYPE,
       phone IN Person.phone%TYPE,
       address IN Person.address%TYPE
       -- more parameters
       )
IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Person ("name", "surname", "phone", "address")
  VALUES (name, surname,phone, address);

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

**The problem is**: Is the any other ways to pass object to oracle? cuz i think its little weird to create procedure with 10+ input parameters. Or better use xml(clob) communication?

Comment: There are *better* ways, but they still involve passing the field parameters independently.

Comment: Why do you create a procedure to run an `INSERT` query when you could run the `INSERT` query directly?

Comment: If you don't want 10+ input parameters in procedure, you can create UDT in oracle and use it. But from C#, you still need to map all the properties. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748619/1705895) for reference.

Comment: @Rajeev thanks, it works. If you will write your answer to the answers block, i will mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want 10+ input parameters in procedure, you can create UDT in oracle and use it.

But from C#, you still need to map all the properties.

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748619/1705895) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Using [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib), you could simply write this as

```
connection.Insert(Person);
```

Dapper will map all of your parameters for you.

Of course, this only works if you're willing to forego stored procedures.  If you insist on stored procedures, you will still have to populate each parameter individually, even with Dapper.